# MKAnnotaionView tapgesture event not getting called

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview

Code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view

    {
        if (![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            CGSize imgSize;
            imgSize = [self getImageWidthHeight:[GRAPHICS MAP_ANNOTATION_DETAIL_BG]];
            CGFloat Width = 0.0;
            CGFloat Height = 0.0;

            Width = imgSize.width;
            Height = imgSize.height;

            callview = [[JoltCalloutCustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((-Width/2) + (view.frameWidth/2), -Height, Width, Height)];
            callview.tag = view.tag;

            NSDictionary *dicList = [m_arrShopList objectAtIndex:view.tag];
            [callview.nameLabel setText:[dicList objectForKey:@"ShopName"]];
            [callview.addressLbl setText:[dicList objectForKey:@"ShopStreet"]];
            [callview.logoImageView setImage:[GRAPHICS LOGIN_BG_IMAGE]];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *annotaionTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(annotationViewTapped:)];
           // annotaionTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            [callview addGestureRecognizer:annotaionTapGesture];

            [view addSubview:callview];


        }
        else{

             [mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:NO]; //hide callout for current location
        }

    }
```

I added customView on AnnotationView.I added tapGesture event to customView.when i tap customView tapgesture event not getting called. What is wrong with my code?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## i Have Found one created a library to show custom callouts.

## tru this, may be helpful to you, @Sarheesh

> DXCustomCallout-ObjC
> [enter link description here](https://github.com/s3lvin/DXCustomCallout-ObjC)

You can pass any custom view for the callout! It supports events for UIControls as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the tap gesture of the MKMapView has the priority over your tap gesture.

You can pick the library above proposed by @Mehul or you can handle this with the following modifications.

In your view controller in which the MKMapView is included (let's say ViewController.m), you have to add a custom MKMapView which could be called CustomMapView.

```
@interface CustomMapView : MKMapView

// This will probably be your JoltCalloutCustomView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *calloutView;

- (void)hideCalloutViewAnimated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
- (void)showCalloutForAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;

@end
```

Then, at the end of ViewController.m, add the following implementation of your CustomMapView.

```
#pragma mark - Custom Map View

@interface MKMapView (UIGestureRecognizer)

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;

@implementation CustomMapView

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]])
        return NO;
    else
        return [super gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:touch];
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIView *calloutMaybe = [self.calloutView hitTest:[self.calloutView convertPoint:point fromView:self] withEvent:event];
    if (calloutMaybe) return calloutMaybe;

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (void)hideCalloutViewAnimated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {

    // Your implementation to hide the callout view
}

- (void)showCalloutForAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {

    // Your implementation to show the callout view
}

@end
```

Now, don't forget to transform your MKMapView into a CustomMapView.

Finally, in your delegate methods of MKMapView, you should have something like this.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

        [_mMapView showCalloutForAnnotationView:view animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

        [_mMapView hideCalloutViewAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

I'm sorry I don't have more time to explain to you in details all the code but if you have any kind of problems, let me know and I will reply ASAP ;)

Have a great day!

Tom.